# Circular progress bar left right edge gets cut

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have created circular progress bar and its working fine but the problem is that the left and right edge gets cut.
[image]

i cant figure out why is it happening or how to fix it.
Its in a relative layout

**Relativelayout containing progressbar**

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/Button_searchdriver_Cancel"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchDriver_center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    >

    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/Progressbar_searchdriver_timer"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/progressbackground"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="60"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circularprogress" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

For background and progress i have the following code -

**Progress drawable**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
    <gradient
    android:centerColor="#ffffff"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:angle="0"
    android:type="sweep"
    android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
    </rotate>
```

**progressbar background**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
    <gradient
    android:centerColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:angle="0"
    android:type="sweep"
    android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>
```

Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set

```
android:innerRadiusRatio="3.0"
```

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

> `innerRadiusRatio` is the radius for the inner part of the ring, expressed as a ratio of the
>   ring's width. For instance, if `android:innerRadiusRatio="5"`, then the
>   inner radius equals the ring's width divided by 5. This value is
>   overridden by `android:innerRadius`. Default value is 9.